# doMC in R and foreach loop not working

Tags: windows, r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

I am trying to get the foreach package for parallel processing in R working and I am having a couple of issues:

The doMC package that is required to make foreach work does not exist on CRAN for Windows. Some blogs suggest that doSNOW instead should do the same job. However, when I run the foreach command with doSNOW, `%dopar%` does not seem to work faster than `%do%`. In fact it is much slower. My CPU is an Intel i7 860 @ 2.80GHz with 8 GB of RAM. Below is my code:

```
##Run example in 1 core 
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)
x= iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"),c(1,5)]
trials = 10000
system.time({
r= foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %do% {
ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
coefficients(results1)
}
})[3]
#  elapsed 
#  37.28 

# Same example in 2 cores
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2,type="SOCK"))
getDoParWorkers()
trials = 10000
system.time({
r= foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE)
results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
coefficients(results1)
}
})[3]
# elapsed 
#  108.14
```

I re-installed all the packages required but still the same problems. Here is the output:

```
sessionInfo()

#R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) 
#Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

#locale:
#[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
#[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

#attached base packages:
#[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods  
#[8] base     

#other attached packages:
#[1] doParallel_1.0.1 codetools_0.2-8  doSNOW_1.0.6     snow_0.3-10     
#[5] iterators_1.0.6  foreach_1.4.0    rcom_2.2-5       rscproxy_2.0-5  

#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] compiler_2.15.1 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: The `%dopar%` example runs faster on my machine, running R-2.15.1, doSNOW_1.0.5, snow_0.3-8, foreach_1.3.2, codetools_0.2-8, and iterators_1.0.5.  What is the output from `sessionInfo` on your machine?

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information. It will be much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

You are better off in Windows to use `doParallel()`:

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(6) #use 6 cores, ie for an 8-core machine
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

Then run your `foreach() %dopar% {}`

EDIT: OP mentioned still seeing the problem, so including my exact code. Running on a 4-core Windows7 VM, R 2.15.1 32-bit, only allowing `doParallel` to use 3 of my cores:

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

x= iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"),c(1,5)]

trials = 1000 
system.time( 
  foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %do% 
  {  
    ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    coefficients(results1) 
  })[3] 

system.time( 
  foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% 
  {  
    ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    coefficients(results1) 
  })[3]
```

In my case, I'm getting 17.6 sec for `%do%` and 14.8 sec for `%dopar%`. Watching the tasks execute, it appears that much of the execution time is the `cbind`, which is a common issue running parallel. In my own simulations, I have done custom work to save my detailed results as part of the parallel task rather than returning them through `foreach`, to remove that part of the overhead. YMMV.

Comment: That worked!! Is it possible to explain why the code in the %dopar% loop needs to be copied repeatedly? Does the number of times the code is copied matter? Thanks for the great help!

Comment: The duplicate code was copied from @Dieter's answer. Maybe he can explain it.

Comment: It's interesting that the vignette "Getting Started with doParallel and foreach" (from which the OP's example comes from) seems to down-play the potential gains of parallel processing. I learned to structure my parallelizations using the `mclapply` examples in the "Package: 'parallel'" vignette. Anyways, I posted how I would implement a parallelized run of the OP's example, which produces a much faster calculation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older question, but I came across it while searching for something else and thought I'd add my solution. I find it more effective to split the overall number of trials into separate groups of trials (the number of groups being equal to the number of processor cores), rather than trying to parallelize all the trials at once and dealing with all the overhead. Here's a comparison using the OP's example:

```
require(doParallel)

x <- iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"),c(1,5)]
trials <- 10000

# example using a single core
t1 <- system.time({
  r1 <- foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %do% {
    ind <- sample(100,100,replace= TRUE)
    results1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    coefficients(results1)
  }
})[3]

# example using 4 cores and parallelizing each model trial
nCores <- 4
cl <- makeCluster(nCores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

t2 <- system.time({
  r2 <- foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
    ind <- sample(100,100,replace= TRUE)
    results1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    coefficients(results1)
  }
})[3]

# example using 4 cores and parallelizing a group of trial runs
trialsPerCore <- as.integer(ceiling(trials / nCores)) # number of trials
                                                   # do to on each core
# function to do a single model run
model <- function(x) {
  ind <- sample(100,100,replace= TRUE)
  results1 <- glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
  coefficients(results1)
}
# function producing a group of model runs
modelRun <- function(trials, x) {
  replicate(trials, model(x))
}
# call the model run for each core
t3 <- system.time(
  r3 <- foreach(icount(nCores), .combine= cbind) %dopar% modelRun(trialsPerCore, x)
)[3]

stopCluster(cl)
```

Execution times on a 3.4 GHz quad-core i7 running Ubuntu 12.04:

```
> t1
elapsed 
   34.5 
> t2
elapsed 
   26.5 
> t3
elapsed 
  8.295
```

Comment: Thanks pistachionut, I was looking for something like this. Does this implementation work on linux? I shall test it shortly myself. If so, you may want to write explicitly if it's a windows-only or cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thîs is not untypical for this type of parallelism, and might depend on the operating system. I had similar result as you, but when I did a silly change in code

```
require(foreach)
require(doSNOW)

x= iris[which(iris[,5] != "setosa"),c(1,5)]

trials = 1000 
system.time( 
  foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %do% 
  {  
    ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit)) 
    coefficients(results1) 
  })[3] 


registerDoSNOW(  makeCluster(2,type="SOCK")) 
getDoParWorkers() 
trials = 1000 
system.time(
  foreach(icount(trials), .combine=cbind) %dopar% 
  {
    ind=sample(100,100,replace=TRUE) 
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    results1 = glm(x[ind,2]~x[ind,1],family=binomial(logit))
    coefficients(results1) 
  })[3]
```

to simulate heavy work in the foreach, I got a break-even for both. This is the price of overhead. I recently had a similar case and handled it directly with MPI, which has much lower overhead, but is much more complex to use (Dirk will disagree, I assume). (Change this to "much less elegant".

Comment: Thanks for your help. It might indeed depend on the OS, since %dopar% works faster on another OS. Thanks again!!