# speed up gls in R?

Tags: r, multicore

I have a Intel i7 quad-core processor. Is it possible to use multiple cores at the same time to calculate a single `gls` model? These can take as much as 5-10 minutes to run, but they only use one core at a time.

If I have four models that take a few minutes each, would it be better to run each model on a separate core?

What options do I have?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11617506/271616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Run your models simultaneously by using a package like parallel, foreach, snow, multicore, etc.
2. Get a build of R with a multi-threaded BLAS.

Note that you should do one or the other of these, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, for #1, can you make a suggestion? Is there a reason to use one over the other? My first instinct is to use parallel because it is written by [Dirk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel). But I recognize that is a faith-based response; others may choose foreach based on similar intuition.

Comment: @Abe: parallel was written by Brian Ripley and the R Core Team, and it's basically a combination of snow and multicore.  I would recommend you use option #1 and read the foreach vignette.  You may also want to consider purchasing [Parallel R](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449309925/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=fotr09-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1449309925), by Q. Ethan McCallum and Stephen Weston.

Comment: thanks I hastily got Dirk's name after googling R parallel and finding the parallel task view. Sounds like I parallel has the benefit of being a part of base R, which would make it my default choice.

Comment: could you say which one is easiest to implement? It would be great to have something as easy as `parallelize(ncores = 3); a1 <- fn(x1); a2 <- fn(x2); a3 <- fn(x3)` with each step run on a separate core? The [basic example](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) for parallel is a page long

Comment: @Abe: you can do something like that with foreach, but it's very hard for me to be more specific unless you provide more details about your problem.

Comment: my problem is that I have 3 `gls` objects that I would like to update with a correlation matrix. The code represented by `fn(x2)` above is something like `update(gls.model, corr = corExp(form = ~x+y))` Would a reproducible example help? Based on `?foreach`, perhaps putting the models in a list (e.g. `models <- list(gls.m1, gls.m2, glsm3)` and then `foreach(i=1:3){models[[i]] <- update(models[[i]], corr = corExp(form = ~x+y)}` would work.

Comment: @Abe: yes, I would try something like that first.  If you have issues, a reproducible example would help... but probably in a new question.